# Delayed job not executed despite disappearing from delayed_jobs table immediately

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I implemented a delayed job in my Rails application, following the [instructions](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).

1. I start the Rails app
2. I click on a link that launches the delayed job
3. The job is visible in the database's `delayed_jobs` table
4. I run `rake jobs:work`
5. The job disappears from the table, so I guess the job has been performed
6. **BUT PROBLEM:** `/tmp/job.log` has not been written (what the job should have done)

The job:

```
class CsvImportJob
  def perform
    File.open('/tmp/job.log', 'w') {|f| f.write("Hello") }
  end
end
```

The call:

```
job = CsvImportJob.new
job.delay.perform
```

Nothing in the logs.
The `rake jobs:work` terminal says nothing after its start message:

```
[Worker(host:nico pid:25453)] Starting job worker
```

Nothing happen either when I launch the job while `rake jobs:work` is running.

In contrast, when the line `"hello".delay.length` is executed, delayed_jobs processes it and a message `String#length completed after 0.0556 -  1 jobs processed at 3.6912 j/s, 0 failed` does appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-undefined_method_xxx_for_class in documentation.

Even delayed_job author don't know the reason. It somehow depends on the webserver you run in on. Try the wiki's recommendation.

See also [delayed_job: NoMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886272/delayed-job-nomethoderror)

Comment: Accepting and granting bounty as it solves my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886272 even though it is not really an answer to this particular question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party, but also look at:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-jobs_are_silently_removed_from_the_database

Your case doesn't sound like a YAML deserialization error, but (as the WIKI suggests), you might set `Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false` so the failed job stays in the table and you can examine the cause of the error.

### update

As I think about it: are you sure that the CsvImportJob class is known to the worker task?  That is, is csv_import_job.rb defined in one of the "well known" directories for a Rails class?  If not, then the worker task won't be able to de-serialize it, which will lead to exactly the behavior that you're seeing.

If for some reason, cav_import_job.rb is not in a well known directory, you can always `require` it from an initialization file -- that should fix the problem.

Comment: That was exactly my problem. I defined the worker in the same file as the model which invoked it. DelayedJobs just failed silently and without any warnings. So make sure you have a separate file and it is using the standard naming conventions.