# Delayed_job not sending email with ActiveMailer 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

I've installed delayed_job for use with ActiveMailer so I can send bulk emails as a background job.  The problem is that although jobs are being installed into the database in the **delayed_jobs** table when the workers pickup up the job no emails are executed.

The details are:

- Rails version 3.2.2
- delayed_job 3.0.3
- delayed_job_active_record 0.3.2

Email jobs are placed onto the queue via a call, as recommended in [Delayed_Job Documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/delayed_job/3.0.3/) for ActiveMailer, with

```
MemberMailer.delay.all_member_email(m, @message)
```

which is  a controller called **email_list_controller** designed to accept a message for sending to one or many members of the site.  After execution  the logfile indicates a SQL INSERT into the delayed_jobs table as show:

```
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `delayed_jobs` (`attempts`, `created_at`, `failed_at`, `handler`, `last_error`, `locked_at`, `locked_by`, `priority`, `queue`, `run_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (0, '2012-07-30 11:42:47', NULL, '--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer\nobject: !ruby/class \'MemberMailer\'\nmethod_name: :all_member_email\nargs:\n- !ruby/ActiveRecord:Member\n attributes:\n id: \n family_id: \n title: \n first_name: FirstName\n last_name: LastName\n middle_initial: \n dob: \n gender: \n home_phone: \n work_phone: \n fax: \n mobile: \n email: grantsayer@gmail.com\n user_id: \n boat_event_id: \n ayf: \n guardian: \n consent: \n created_at: \n updated_at: \n- !ruby/ActiveRecord:Message\n attributes:\n id: 1\n subject: ! \'[IGNORE] - Testing\'\n body: ! \"<b>A body</b>\\r\\nMore lines\\r\\nAnother line \\r\\nStuff\\r\\nMore Stuff How\n to do more stuff\\r\\n\"\n created_at: 2012-04-20 04:17:51.000000000 Z\n updated_at: 2012-07-30 10:06:09.000000000 Z\n sent: 1\n date: 2012-04-20\n', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, '2012-07-30 11:42:47', '2012-07-30 11:42:47')
(26.8ms)  COMMIT
```

and very quickly thereafter the worker deletes the job

```
SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `delayed_jobs` WHERE `delayed_jobs`.`id` = 8
```

The worker job is initiated via the rake task

```
rake jobs:work
```

There is no record of the email being sent or received.

The email process normally works when testing without the delayed_job method

```
MemberMailer.all_member_email(m, @message).deliver
```

with email being sent, delivered through the appropriate path.

Has anyone else experienced this problem ?  General 'oogling' showed that there were problems with earlier versions of delayed_job and invalid objects.  From the data in the DB it appears that the YAML serialized information looks ok.

Comment: Where is `MememberMailer`? Is working without using `delay`? How about log something in the all_meember_email?

Comment: Have you start delayed_job server using command `script/delayed_job start` before starting rails server???

Comment: I've tested the MemberMailer without delay and it works ok

Comment: I've only started the script/delayed_job start after starting rails so i'll give your suggestion a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I would expect the worker correctly doing it's job. The job gets removed from the queue when the worker thinks it's job is done and there is no exception happening.

`delayed_job` has [several configuration options](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#gory-details) that you can tweak in an initializer. The default setting means 25 retries with several minutes delay.

I would suggest looking into the `MemberMailer.all_member_email` method. A common mistake is referencing instance variables or methods there.

If it doesn't help please post the code of you `MemberMailer` class.

Comment: Thanks - i'll try some of the configuration options as well as check the instance variables usage.  I'm not seeing the job remain in the database with the status set to failed.  It is simply deleted, as though it's completed successfully.

Comment: As described by iltempo setting delayed_job to log more information showed up the problem as indicated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886272/delayed-job-nomethoderror This meant I could see a problem since the log showed it was serializing an Object, not a Class.  In other words falling back on the lowest common denominator of Object.  Further investigation into the method showed a problem with an instance variable not be referenced correctly.

Comment: Hi Grant, could you please tell me where do I find the Log? I'm having the exact same problem(s) as you did.